# loading dynamic assets vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to load and display images dynamically from assets folder in my vuejs project, but it's not working, this is my code

This does not work:

```
<img :src="getSource(data.thumbnail)" :alt="data.name"/>


   getSource(path){
      return new URL(`@/assets/${path}`, import.meta.url).href;
    }
```

but if I use the same code with URL statically it works...:

```
<img :src="getSource(data.thumbnail)" :alt="data.name"/>


   getSource(path){
      return new URL("@/assets/moon-mode-thumbnail.jpg", import.meta.url).href;
    }
```

Do I need to cast `@/assets/${path}` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A SOLUTION, it works in vuejs 3 to load images from assets dynamically, here it is:

template

```
<img :src="getSrc(data.thumbnail)" :alt="data.name"/>
```

script

```
getSrc(path){
      let src = require.context('@/assets/', false);
      return src('./' + path );
    }
```